# Using a Conditional Expression with a Method in C#

Tags: c#

I have a `List<Animal>` where the `Animal` that has a:

```
int GetId();
```

that returns an Id of the Animal.

Given an Id,  what would be the best way to get the specific Animal? I'm wondering if there's a correct way to do the following:

```
targetId = 2;
targetAnimal = animalList.Select(a => a.GetId() == targetId)
```

Comment: It is problematic to describe the expected outcome with the actual code. But if I understand you correctly, just use `Where` instead of `Select` and you're good to go.

Comment: sorry for the confusion but yes, that's what I'm looking for

Comment: `where` will return a collection (an `IEnumerable`, actually) of animals. if you know you are looking for a single element (i.e. there will be only one Animal with that ID), `First` or `FirstOrDefault` can be a better choice

Comment: You can use list's `Find` method or linq `First`, `FirstOrDefault` methods.

Comment: Also if you're doing a lot of lookups on one particular property, and you have a big list, you might consider using a `Dictionary<>` to store them, which will internally use hash tables to improve performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try these methods

**.Single or .SingleOrDefault**

```
targetAnimal = animalList.SingleOrDefault(a => a.GetId() == targetId)
```

**.First or .FirstOrDefault**

```
targetAnimal = animalList.FirstOrDefault(a => a.GetId() == targetId)
```

You might wanna know more about these functions

**Single()** - There is exactly 1 result, an exception is thrown if no result is returned or more than one result.

**SingleOrDefault()** – Same as Single(), but it can handle the null value.

**First()** - There is at least one result, an exception is thrown if no result is returned.

**FirstOrDefault()** - Same as First(), but not thrown any exception or return null when there is no result.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `FirstOrDefault`:

```
var targetAnimal = animalList.FirstOrDefault(a => a.GetId() == targetId);
```

If any Animal found in the list, whose `Id` matches the `targetId`, this would be assigned to `targetAnimal`. Otherwise `targetAnimal` would be null.

For further info regarding this method, please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`First`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535050(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx) methods.

The former will throw an exception if no element has the ID ; the latter will return `default(T)` (which will be `null` for a reference type (class) and all fields initialized to default for a value type (struct)).

```
return animalList.First(a => a.GetId() == targetID);
```

And

```
return animalList.FirstOrDefault(a => a.GetId() == targetID);
```

If you want to return a default/fallback value instead of `default(T)`, you can use the null-coalescing operator:

```
return animalList.FirstOrDefault(a => a.GetId() == targetID) ?? theFallbackValue;
```

Comment: `??` won't work for an `int` as it  cannot be `null`, you would have to cast the result of the `FirstOrDefault` to `int?` for that to work

Answer (score 1):

Select is to "select" values, if you want types, you want to filter with Where.

Example:

```
targetAnimal = animalList.Where(animal => animal.GetId() == targetId)
                         .First()
```

However, first admits a condition, so you can skip the Where and use First directly:

```
targetAnimal = animalList.First(animal => animal.GetId() == targetId)
```

Furthermore, this will throw an error if no animal with that Id is found. If you want it to return null, use FirstOrDefault

```
targetAnimal = animalList.FirstOrDefault(animal => animal.GetId() == targetId)
```